# Python solution for USACO Silver Question Wormhole Sort

Tags: python, performance, binary-search, depth-first-search

I'm struggling a bit with a USACO silver question using python, http://usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=992.

Basically, I think my code is correct, but I can't figure out a way to make it more efficient as I simply run out of time in the 5 test cases with larger input data.

Here's my code:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(200000)

#file open
fin = open("wormsort.in", "r")
fout = open("wormsort.out", "w")

#read file
temp = fin.readline().strip().split(" ")
n, m = int(temp[0]), int(temp[1])
cows = list(map(int, fin.readline().strip().split(" ")))
temp = [i for i in range(1, n+1)]

#if cows are already sorted
if cows == temp:
    fout.write(str(-1)+ "\n")
    quit()
adjacency = {i: set() for i in range(1, n + 1)}


#sorting wormhole by weight
weight = []
for i in range(m):
    temp = list(map(int, fin.readline().strip().split(" "))) #temp storage for wormhold read
    weight.append(temp[2])
    adjacency[temp[1]].add((temp[0], temp[2]))
    adjacency[temp[0]].add((temp[1], temp[2]))
weight.sort()

tvis = [0 for _ in range(n)]

def dfs(pre, bound, color): #dfs for a single component
    tvis[pre[0]-1] = color

    for i in adjacency[pre[0]]:
        if not tvis[i[0]-1] and i[1] >= bound:
            dfs(i, bound, color)


def check(k): #check if match condition given a min weight k
    counter = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        counter += 1
        if tvis[i-1] == 0:
            dfs((i, 10**9), k, counter)
        else:
            continue

    for i in range(len(tvis)):
        if tvis[cows[i]-1] == tvis[i]:
            continue
        else:
            return False
    return True

high = m-1
low = 0
#binary search
while low != high:
    tvis = [0 for _ in range(n)]
    mid = (high+low)//2


    if check(weight[mid]):
        low = mid+1
    else:
        high = mid

fout.write(str(weight[low-1])+ "\n")
```

The idea is that since I am trying to find a maximum least weight wormhole, I could use binary search to improve efficiency compared to linear, and in the linear search use dfs for every check to see if each connected component have both the position and the cow included.

Comment: If your code runs without error and produces the correct result then you'll get better feedback on performance, style, technique if you repost your question over at the [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct about your code running in O(n(n+m)*log n) --- log n is from the binary search, n is from the `for` loop inside of `def check(k)`, and n+m is from the dfs --- and it still doesn't run under the time limit, there is a possibility that the problem may be impossible to solve in Python.

In the USACO Contest Instructions and Rules, it says, "On some problems (particularly in higher divisions), it may not be possible to solve all inputs within the requisite running time using Python, due to its slowness."

You might have to switch to another language for this problem like C++

Answer (score -1):

You can solve with DSU using python however that is a gold topic

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).